# Difference Between build_depends and find_package components

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between listing something as a build_depends and listing it in the find_package macro? It seems redundant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88306/difference-between-build_depends-and-find_package-components/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It mostly is redundant.

Some system dependencies declare non-standard CMake variables, so the CMake interface does need to be spelled out explicitly somewhere, and CMakeLists.txt is a reasonable choice.

Because CMake scripts are not easy for other tools to parse, some information is duplicated in package.xml, where it is more-readily accessible.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-07**:
So you need to take care of both files simultaneously? Not very efficient...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-10-07**:
There is also this option: https://github.com/wjwwood/catkin_simple .

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-10-07**:
Was that ever advertised?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-07**:
FYI, catkin_simple is very unstable, it might change, without warning, in the future (names, api, etc..). I would recommend forking it if you want to use it. It was never advertised because it isn't finished, it doesn't support actions or dynamic_reconfigure and has almost no documentation.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-09**:
There are also cases when you do not want all the dependencies in the CMakeLists.txt if you have dependencies on non-C style packages which provide potentially other resources or tools not able to be integrated into CMake.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package.xml files contain rosdep keys for system dependencies as well as ROS package names. Sadly there is simply no 1-to-1 mapping between those and the `find_package()` names. So any heuristic (like as it is done in `catkin_simple`) will never work 100% reliable. That is the reason why the developer has to specify them separately.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-07**:
That is pretty stupid in my book... Unnecessary redundant redundancy. Who could take care of this flaw?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-07**:
@Hendrik_SeveQ_Wiese `catkin_simple` tries to deal with this, but will fail if a caktin dependency is missing. Basically, for each `build_depend` it calls `find_package(build_depend)` and if it is not found it assumes it is a System package which either doesn't have a CMake Module or doesn't set canonical CMake variables, but it could be that it actually is a catkin package but is not present. There is no way to distinguish between the two cases.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-10-08**:
How did rosbuild deal with it?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-08**:
It just did not. It gets the pkg-config information for all ROS dependencies. But for non-ROS dependencies the developer has to deal with it manually - just because there is no way to do that in a generic way.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-08**:
@David Lu rosbuild differentiated between rosbuild packages and system packages,  vs  tags. But the  tags were not used in packaging, so you had to maintain a second, redundant stack level dependency tree when releasing your code.